# Fan in tiny bathroom has no vent. Is there a better option to absorb/reduce moisture/odors?

Tags: bathroom, ventilation, fans

I lease an apartment and was just cleaning the light/fan combo (a [NuTone NUA-40LN](http://feed.phacproducts.com/Nutone/NUTONE%20PARTS%202/parts/Fans/NUA40L,%20_NUA40LNparts.pdf)) in the ceiling of my very tiny but full bathroom and realized the fan in the ceiling is just blowing air around, but not actually *out* anywhere.

It's an old unit, and I imagine there might be better options now for folks who can't vent outward.

I live in an old building and my landlord isn't likely to pay for any sort of line. But I could make the case for replacing this unit and would be cool with doing it myself if you know of better options. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are sure it is not connected to duct work? . A fan that pushes the moist air around is not doing any thing but pushing moist air around. Installing a new proper  fan would require ducting to the exterior.

Comment: Could you edit your post to include a picture of the fan. Maybe even a brand/model number?

Comment: NuTone model NUA-40LN

http://feed.phacproducts.com/Nutone/NUTONE%20PARTS%202/parts/Fans/NUA40L,%20_NUA40LNparts.pdf

Comment: Do you have central a/c and or forced air heat in the apartment? If so, is there an outlet vent in the bathroom? If you turn the fan on while you are bathing and for a time afterwards, this will help dry the bathroom.

Comment: Have you pulled off the light cover and the grill to look inside to be sure there's no duct leading out?

Comment: @FreeMan Yes. No duct leading out. The fan and light fixture is sitting in what is essentially a five-sided metal box in the ceiling.

Comment: Yeesh! Any indication of a punch out that was _supposed_ to be removed to lead to the duct, but wasn't? A bathroom fan without some sort of exit ducting is just... weird...