# How to paint a small bathroom with very poor ventilation?

Tags: bathroom, paint, mold, moisture

Amateur here, just trying to do his best.

How to paint a small bathroom with very poor ventilation?

I imagine I'd want a paint that seals the paint behind it (*which has been prone to a little mold*), and one that is also mold/mildew-proof, right?

What type of paint/procedure is best for a tiny full bathroom that has very poor ventilation?

Comment: Have you thought about improving the ventilation (i.e. adding a fan) before you paint?  If your mold issues are due to excessive moisture, a fan will lilkely help more than choosing the right paint will.

Comment: @NateS. OP is asking about that in another question.  https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/200013/fan-in-tiny-bathroom-has-no-vent-is-there-a-better-option-to-absorb-reduce-mois

Comment: Which question? What paint? How to piant? Are you good at cutting in? And fix the existing ventilation first as per your other question.

Comment: Can you clarify your question: Are you asking about ventilating the room while the paint's wet to help get rid of the smell, or are you talking about adding permanent ventilation to the room? Please [edit] your post to let us know which it is or you'll get confused answers and questioning comments.

Answer (score 0):

Just get a simple portable fan to blow fresh air into the bathroom. Open other windows to provide additional fresh air...maybe via another portable fan.

Comment: Due to the mold, improving the ventilation permanently is the way to go.

Comment: Sure Solar Mike, but even a better exhaust fan isn't much a match for freshly painted walls.  I was just separating the 2 requirements.